# Best way to align text on my screen based on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Currently I am building an interactive personal resume type website for myself. Im just having a minor issue of centering my text based on the screen size which I am pretty sure there is a simple fix. Here is an image of how the text shows up currently based off of what my code does ---> [image: Current display based off code]

Here is the code that does this

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('game');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
window.addEventListener('resize', (e) => {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  })
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(255,255,255,.6)";

// Constants in objects doesnt work cause objects passing as reference and will by modified!
// If you want constant constant, use primitives
const SPACESHIP_SIZE = { width: 15, height: 25 };
const SPACESHIP_POSITION = { x: window.innerWidth/2, y: window.innerHeight/2};
const GRAVITY = 1;
const HOVER_TICKS = 20;
//Update thrust constant
const THRUST = 15;

const Systems = {
    'main': {
        holes:[
            {x: window.innerWidth/8, y: window.innerHeight/3, size: 40, dest: 'Education'},
            {x: window.innerWidth/8, y: window.innerHeight/1.15, size: 40, dest: 'Technical Skills'},
            {x: window.innerWidth/2, y: window.innerHeight/3, size: 40, dest: 'Experience1'},
            {x: window.innerWidth/2, y: window.innerHeight/1.15, size: 40, dest: 'Experience2'},
            {x: window.innerWidth/1.1, y: window.innerHeight/3, size: 40, dest: 'Contact Me'},
        ]
        
    },
    'Education': {holes:[{x: window.innerWidth-100, y: window.innerHeight-100, size: 40, dest: 'main'}]},
    
    'Technical Skills': {holes:[{x: window.innerWidth-100, y: window.innerHeight-100, size: 40, dest: 'main'}]},
    
    'Experience1': {holes:[{x: window.innerWidth-100, y: window.innerHeight-100, size: 40, dest: 'main'}]},
    
    'Experience2': {holes:[{x: window.innerWidth-100, y: window.innerHeight-100, size: 40, dest: 'main'}]},

    'Personal Projects': {holes:[{x: window.innerWidth-100, y: window.innerHeight-100, size: 40, dest: 'main'}]},
    
    'Contact Me': {holes:[{x: window.innerWidth-100, y: window.innerHeight-100, size: 40, dest: 'main'}]},
    
};

let spaceShip;
let currentSystem = 'main';
const spaceObjects = [];

class SpaceObject {
    constructor(size, position, color = 'black', angle = 0) {
        this.color = color;
        this.size = size;
        this.position = position;
        this.angle = angle;
        spaceObjects.push(this);
    }
    tick() {
        this.update();
        this.draw();
    }
    update() {}
    draw() {}
    isAbove({x, y}) {
        return Math.abs(this.position.x - x) < this.size && Math.abs(this.position.y - y) < this.size;
    }
    destroy() {
        spaceObjects.splice(spaceObjects.indexOf(this), 1);
    }
}

class SpaceShip extends SpaceObject {
    constructor(size, position) {
        super(size, position, 'yellow');
        this.aboveHole = 0;
        this.engineOn = false;
        this.rotatingLeft = false;
        this.rotatingRight = false;
        this.velocity = {x: 0, y: 0};
    }

    draw() {
        const triangleCenterX = this.position.x + 0.5 * this.size.width;
        const triangleCenterY = this.position.y + 0.5 * this.size.height;
        ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(triangleCenterX, triangleCenterY);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.beginPath();
        // Triangle
        ctx.moveTo(0, -this.size.height / 2);
        ctx.lineTo(-this.size.width / 2, this.size.height / 2);
        ctx.lineTo(this.size.width / 2, this.size.height / 2);
        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fill();

        // Flame for engine
        if (this.engineOn) {
            const fireYPos = this.size.height / 2 + 4;
            const fireXPos = this.size.width * 0.25;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(-fireXPos, fireYPos);
            ctx.lineTo(fireXPos, fireYPos);
            ctx.lineTo(0, fireYPos + Math.random() * 100);
            ctx.lineTo(-fireXPos, fireYPos);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
            ctx.fill();
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }

    update() {
        this.moveSpaceShip();
        this.checkAboveHole();
    }

    moveSpaceShip() {
        // Angle has to be in radians
        const degToRad = Math.PI / 180;
        // Change the position based on velocity
        this.position.x += this.velocity.x;
        this.position.y += this.velocity.y;
        // Move spaceship to other side when leaving screen
        this.position.x = (canvas.width + this.position.x) % canvas.width;
        this.position.y = (canvas.height + this.position.y) % canvas.height;
        /*
         Adding floating point numbers to the end of the
         rotaion handling to make roation faster
         */
        if (this.rotatingLeft) this.angle -= (degToRad+.15);
        if (this.rotatingRight) this.angle += (degToRad+.15);


        // Acceleration
        if (this.engineOn) {
            this.velocity.x += (THRUST / 100) * Math.sin(this.angle);
            this.velocity.y -= (THRUST / 100) * Math.cos(this.angle);
        }
        // Update the velocity depending on gravity
        this.velocity.y += GRAVITY / 2500;
    }

    checkAboveHole() {
        const hole = spaceObjects.find(spaceObject => spaceObject !== this && spaceObject.isAbove(this.position));
        if(hole) {
            this.aboveHole++;
            if(this.aboveHole > HOVER_TICKS) {
                confirm(`Jump to system ${hole.dest}?`) && jump(hole);
                this.aboveHole = 0;
            }
        } else {
            this.aboveHole = 0;
        }
    }
}


const circle = (ctx, x, y, radius, color = 'white') => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
};

class BlackHole extends SpaceObject {
    constructor(size, position, dest) {
        super(size, position);
        this.dest = dest;
    }
    update() {
        // Spin?
        this.angle+=.01;
    }
    draw() {
        // Shadow
        ctx.shadowBlur = this.size >>> 2;
        circle(ctx, this.position.x, this.position.y, this.size + 1, `rgba(255, 255, 255, .6)`);
        // Hole
        circle(ctx, this.position.x, this.position.y, this.size, this.color);
        // Spinning view
        circle(ctx, this.position.x + (this.size * Math.sin(this.angle) - 1), this.position.y + (this.size * Math.cos(this.angle) - 1), 2, 'gray');
        circle(ctx, this.position.x - (this.size * Math.sin(this.angle) - 1), this.position.y - (this.size * Math.cos(this.angle) - 1), 2, 'gray');
    }
}

function handleKeyInput(event) {
    const { keyCode, type } = event;
    const isKeyDown = type === 'keydown' ? true : false;

    if (keyCode === 37) spaceShip.rotatingLeft = isKeyDown;
    if (keyCode === 39) spaceShip.rotatingRight = isKeyDown;
    if (keyCode === 38) spaceShip.engineOn = isKeyDown;
}

function jump({dest}) {
    currentSystem = dest || 'main';
    while(spaceObjects.length) spaceObjects[0].destroy();
    Systems[currentSystem].holes.forEach(hole => new BlackHole(hole.size, {x: hole.x, y: hole.y}, hole.dest));
    spaceShip = new SpaceShip(SPACESHIP_SIZE, SPACESHIP_POSITION);
    
}

function draw() {
    // Clear screen
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 10, 60)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(150, 150, 150)';
    ctx.fillText(`--> You are in ${currentSystem}`, window.innerWidth-(window.innerWidth-150), window.innerHeight-(window.innerHeight/1.05));
    ctx.fillText(`--> Use the arrow keys to guide the rocket into different portals`, window.innerWidth-(window.innerWidth-426), window.innerHeight-(window.innerHeight/1.08));
    ctx.fillText(`--> Refresh the page if you resize your window`, window.innerWidth-(window.innerWidth-312), window.innerHeight-(window.innerHeight/1.11));
    
    
    //Adding section/system text information
    /*
    if(currentSystem=='main'){
        ctx.font ='bolder 20px Courier New'
        ctx.fillText('Education Portal', window.innerWidth/9, window.innerHeight/4);
        ctx.fillText('Technical Skills Portal', window.innerWidth/9.2, window.innerHeight/1.27);
        ctx.fillText('Experience Portal', window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/4);
        ctx.fillText('Experience Portal', window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/1.27);
        ctx.fillText('Contact Me', window.innerWidth/1.25, window.innerHeight/4);

    }
    */

    if(currentSystem=='main'){
        ctx.font ='bolder 20px Courier New';
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.fillText('Education Portal', Systems['main'].holes[0].x, Systems['main'].holes[0].y - 50);
        ctx.fillText('Technical Skills Portal', Systems['main'].holes[1].x, Systems['main'].holes[1].y - 50);
        ctx.fillText('Experience Portal', Systems['main'].holes[2].x, Systems['main'].holes[2].y - 50);
        ctx.fillText('Experience Portal', Systems['main'].holes[3].x, Systems['main'].holes[3].y - 50);
        ctx.fillText('Contact Me', Systems['main'].holes[4].x, Systems['main'].holes[4].y - 50);
    }


    if(currentSystem=='Education'){  
        //College
        ctx.font = 'italic 20px Courier New';
        ctx.fillText('Binghamton University, State University of New York, ', window.innerWidth-(window.innerWidth-150), 150);
        ctx.fillText('Thomas J. Watson College of Engineering and Applied Science', window.innerWidth-(window.innerWidth-150), 170);
        ctx.fillText('Bachelor of Science in Computer Science', window.innerWidth-(window.innerWidth-150), 190);
        
        ctx.font = '20px Courier New';
        ctx.fillText('Overall GPA: 3.92', window.innerWidth-(window.innerWidth-150), 210);
        ctx.fillText('Major GPA: 4.0', window.innerWidth-(window.innerWidth-150), 230);

        ctx.fillText('Relevant Coursework: Programming and Hardware Fundamentals,', window.innerWidth-(window.innerWidth-150), 270);
        ctx.fillText('Professional Skills, Ethics, and CS Trends,', window.innerWidth-(window.innerWidth-150), 290)
        ctx.fillText('Data Structures and Algorithms, Programming with Objects and Data Structures,', window.innerWidth-(window.innerWidth-150), 310);
        ctx.fillText('Architecture from a Programmer Perspective (By Fall 2021)', window.innerWidth-(window.innerWidth-150), 330);

        //High School
        ctx.font = 'italic 20px Courier New';
        ctx.fillText('Islip High School', window.innerWidth-(window.innerWidth-150), 430);
        ctx.fillText('STEM Academy Honors', window.innerWidth-(window.innerWidth-150), 450);
        ctx.font = '20px Courier New';
        ctx.fillText('Overall GPA: 100.77, Top 5% of class', window.innerWidth-(window.innerWidth-150), 470);

        ctx.fillText('Return', Systems['Education'].holes[0].x, Systems['Education'].holes[0].y-50);

    }


    if(currentSystem=='Technical Skills'){
        ctx.font = '20px Courier New';
        ctx.fillText('Languages: Python, Java, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, C++',50 , 150);
        ctx.fillText('Software and OS: VS Code, Eclipse, Sublime Text, Git, Logisim, Anaconda,',50 , 190);
        ctx.fillText('Spyder, Microsoft Office, Linux, MacOS',50 , 210);
        ctx.fillText('Additional: Familiar with MySQL, Arduino',50 , 250);

        ctx.fillText('Return', window.innerWidth-135 , window.innerHeight-155);
    }


    if(currentSystem=='Experience1'){
        ctx.font = '20px Courier New';
        ctx.fillText('Binghamton University Rover Team, Software Engineer | Binghamton, NY',50 , 150);
        ctx.fillText('October 2020 - Prestent',50 , 170);
        
        ctx.fillText('-->Designed networks and code bases using C++ to maximize the efficiency',50 , 190);
        ctx.fillText('   and performance of a model mars rover for The Mars Society University',50 , 210);
        ctx.fillText('   Rover Challenge which takes place yearly', 50, 230);
        
        ctx.fillText('-->Built a custom username/password page by interfacing Google Firebase', 50, 250);
        ctx.fillText('   with a HTML, CSS, and JavaScript page which allowed for user', 50, 270);     
        ctx.fillText('   authentication, permitting members of the team to view classified documents', 50, 290);
        
        ctx.fillText('-->Prepared rover data by implementing Python script from scratch', 50, 310);
        ctx.fillText('   using Matplotlib and NumPy which led to data visualization to be analyzed', 50, 330);

        ctx.fillText('-->Constructed the GUI for the base station computer in C++ so', 50, 350);
        ctx.fillText('   that all the components of the rover could be viewed in the most effective way', 50, 370);
        

        ctx.fillText('JPMorgan Chase, Software Engineering Virtual Experience Program | Remote Role',50 , 460);
        ctx.fillText('July 2020 - September 2020',50 , 480);
        ctx.fillText('-->Modified an interface with a stock price data feed using Python 3 so that the system/data could be analyzed',50 , 500);
        ctx.fillText('-->Implemented the perspective open-source code in preparation for data visualization',50 , 520);
        ctx.fillText('-->Received certificate of completion by end of program',50 , 540);

        ctx.fillText('Return', window.innerWidth-135 , window.innerHeight-155);
    }


    if(currentSystem=='Experience2'){
        ctx.font = '20px Courier New';
        ctx.fillText('Google CSSI, Coursera, Software Engineering Student | Remote Role',50 , 150);
        ctx.fillText('June 2020 - August 2020', 50, 170);
        ctx.fillText('-->Selected to take part in an invite-only Google Tech Student Development program', 50, 190);
        ctx.fillText('-->Developed/designed personal web pages through CodePen using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript', 50, 210);
        ctx.fillText('-->Reviewed, designed, and implemented a green screen algorithm in JavaScript', 50, 230);
        ctx.fillText(' to transform images on our developed web pages', 50, 250);
        ctx.fillText('-->Learned to hide data in images through the use of steganography', 50, 270);
        ctx.fillText('-->Received certificate of completion by end of program', 50, 290);





        ctx.fillText('Return', window.innerWidth-135 , window.innerHeight-155);
    }


    if(currentSystem=='Contact Me'){
        ctx.fillText('Contact Me',50 , 450);
        ctx.fillText('Return', window.innerWidth-135 , window.innerHeight-155);    
    }






    //Loading small stars
    ctx.shadowBlur = 1;
    for (var i = 1, j = 1; j<canvas.height; i+=100, i > canvas.width && (i=1, j+=100), circle(ctx, i, j, 1));

    //loading medium stars
    ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
    for (var i = 1, j = 1; j<canvas.height; i+=150, i > canvas.width && (i=1, j+=150), circle(ctx, i, j, 2));

    //loading larger stars
    ctx.shadowBlur = 3;
    for (var i = 1, j = 1; j<canvas.height; i+=225, i > canvas.width && (i=1, j+=225), circle(ctx, i, j, 3));

    // tick all objects
    spaceObjects.forEach(spaceObject => spaceObject.tick());

    // Repeats
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

// Event Listeners
document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyInput);
document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyInput);
// Start the game
jump({dest: 'main'});
draw();
```

The picture above is in the education section, I just want the text to be all neat and aligned despite the size of the desktop screen. Are there any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: fyi the reason you text is starting off screen is because it all inherits `textAlign = “center”`. If you want each of your pages to have the text aligned back to the left you need to set `textAlign = “left”` after you draw `main`

Answer (score 0):

Use `canvas.width/2` for the center of the x axis. You already have `textAlign = “center”` so the text should align to the center of the canvas.

```
ctx.fillText('Binghamton University, State University of New York, ', canvas.width/2, 150);
```

Also everywhere you are using `window.innerWidth/Height` I would recommend replacing with canvas.x/y so you are placing items in relation to the canvas.

Here's your code with a couple changes. I moved the text to render after the stars in the draw function. I also put each body of text into it's own function and then that function can be called in the draw loop. This will prevent any positioning errors when the canvas is resized. Lastly I changed all of the `innerWidth/Height` to `canvas.width/height` and moved the listener for resize down to the bottom.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("game");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;

ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(255,255,255,.6)";

// Constants in objects doesnt work cause objects passing as reference and will by modified!
// If you want constant constant, use primitives
const SPACESHIP_SIZE = {
    width: 15,
    height: 25
};
const SPACESHIP_POSITION = {
    x: canvas.width / 2,
    y: canvas.height / 2
};
const GRAVITY = 1;
const HOVER_TICKS = 20;
//Update thrust constant
const THRUST = 15;

const Systems = {
    main: {
        holes: [{
                x: canvas.width / 8,
                y: canvas.height / 3,
                size: 40,
                dest: "Education"
            },
            {
                x: canvas.width / 8,
                y: canvas.height / 1.15,
                size: 40,
                dest: "Technical Skills"
            },
            {
                x: canvas.width / 2,
                y: canvas.height / 3,
                size: 40,
                dest: "Experience1"
            },
            {
                x: canvas.width / 2,
                y: canvas.height / 1.15,
                size: 40,
                dest: "Experience2"
            },
            {
                x: canvas.width / 1.1,
                y: canvas.height / 3,
                size: 40,
                dest: "Contact Me"
            }
        ]
    },
    Education: {
        holes: [{
            x: canvas.width - 100,
            y: canvas.height - 100,
            size: 40,
            dest: "main"
        }]
    },

    "Technical Skills": {
        holes: [{
            x: canvas.width - 100,
            y: canvas.height - 100,
            size: 40,
            dest: "main"
        }]
    },

    Experience1: {
        holes: [{
            x: canvas.width - 100,
            y: canvas.height - 100,
            size: 40,
            dest: "main"
        }]
    },

    Experience2: {
        holes: [{
            x: canvas.width - 100,
            y: canvas.height - 100,
            size: 40,
            dest: "main"
        }]
    },

    "Personal Projects": {
        holes: [{
            x: canvas.width - 100,
            y: canvas.height - 100,
            size: 40,
            dest: "main"
        }]
    },

    "Contact Me": {
        holes: [{
            x: canvas.width - 100,
            y: canvas.height - 100,
            size: 40,
            dest: "main"
        }]
    }
};

let spaceShip;
let currentSystem = "main";
const spaceObjects = [];

class SpaceObject {
    constructor(size, position, color = "black", angle = 0) {
        this.color = color;
        this.size = size;
        this.position = position;
        this.angle = angle;
        spaceObjects.push(this);
    }
    tick() {
        this.update();
        this.draw();
    }
    update() {}
    draw() {}
    isAbove({
        x,
        y
    }) {
        return (
            Math.abs(this.position.x - x) < this.size &&
            Math.abs(this.position.y - y) < this.size
        );
    }
    destroy() {
        spaceObjects.splice(spaceObjects.indexOf(this), 1);
    }
}

class SpaceShip extends SpaceObject {
    constructor(size, position) {
        super(size, position, "yellow");
        this.aboveHole = 0;
        this.engineOn = false;
        this.rotatingLeft = false;
        this.rotatingRight = false;
        this.velocity = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        };
    }

    draw() {
        const triangleCenterX = this.position.x + 0.5 * this.size.width;
        const triangleCenterY = this.position.y + 0.5 * this.size.height;
        ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(triangleCenterX, triangleCenterY);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.beginPath();
        // Triangle
        ctx.moveTo(0, -this.size.height / 2);
        ctx.lineTo(-this.size.width / 2, this.size.height / 2);
        ctx.lineTo(this.size.width / 2, this.size.height / 2);
        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fill();

        // Flame for engine
        if (this.engineOn) {
            const fireYPos = this.size.height / 2 + 4;
            const fireXPos = this.size.width * 0.25;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(-fireXPos, fireYPos);
            ctx.lineTo(fireXPos, fireYPos);
            ctx.lineTo(0, fireYPos + Math.random() * 100);
            ctx.lineTo(-fireXPos, fireYPos);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
            ctx.fill();
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }

    update() {
        this.moveSpaceShip();
        this.checkAboveHole();
    }

    moveSpaceShip() {
        // Angle has to be in radians
        const degToRad = Math.PI / 180;
        // Change the position based on velocity
        this.position.x += this.velocity.x;
        this.position.y += this.velocity.y;
        // Move spaceship to other side when leaving screen
        this.position.x = (canvas.width + this.position.x) % canvas.width;
        this.position.y = (canvas.height + this.position.y) % canvas.height;
        /*
             Adding floating point numbers to the end of the
             rotaion handling to make roation faster
             */
        if (this.rotatingLeft) this.angle -= degToRad + 0.15;
        if (this.rotatingRight) this.angle += degToRad + 0.15;

        // Acceleration
        if (this.engineOn) {
            this.velocity.x += (THRUST / 100) * Math.sin(this.angle);
            this.velocity.y -= (THRUST / 100) * Math.cos(this.angle);
        }
        // Update the velocity depending on gravity
        this.velocity.y += GRAVITY / 2500;
    }

    checkAboveHole() {
        const hole = spaceObjects.find(
            (spaceObject) =>
            spaceObject !== this && spaceObject.isAbove(this.position)
        );
        if (hole) {
            this.aboveHole++;
            if (this.aboveHole > HOVER_TICKS) {
                confirm(`Jump to system ${hole.dest}?`) && jump(hole);
                this.aboveHole = 0;
            }
        } else {
            this.aboveHole = 0;
        }
    }
}

const circle = (ctx, x, y, radius, color = "white") => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
};

class BlackHole extends SpaceObject {
    constructor(size, position, dest) {
        super(size, position);
        this.dest = dest;
    }
    update() {
        // Spin?
        this.angle += 0.01;
    }
    draw() {
        // Shadow
        ctx.shadowBlur = this.size >>> 2;
        circle(
            ctx,
            this.position.x,
            this.position.y,
            this.size + 1,
            `rgba(255, 255, 255, .6)`
        );
        // Hole
        circle(ctx, this.position.x, this.position.y, this.size, this.color);
        // Spinning view
        circle(
            ctx,
            this.position.x + (this.size * Math.sin(this.angle) - 1),
            this.position.y + (this.size * Math.cos(this.angle) - 1),
            2,
            "gray"
        );
        circle(
            ctx,
            this.position.x - (this.size * Math.sin(this.angle) - 1),
            this.position.y - (this.size * Math.cos(this.angle) - 1),
            2,
            "gray"
        );
    }
}

function handleKeyInput(event) {
    const {
        keyCode,
        type
    } = event;
    const isKeyDown = type === "keydown" ? true : false;

    if (keyCode === 37) spaceShip.rotatingLeft = isKeyDown;
    if (keyCode === 39) spaceShip.rotatingRight = isKeyDown;
    if (keyCode === 38) spaceShip.engineOn = isKeyDown;
}

function jump({
    dest
}) {
    currentSystem = dest || "main";
    while (spaceObjects.length) spaceObjects[0].destroy();
    Systems[currentSystem].holes.forEach(
        (hole) => new BlackHole(hole.size, {
            x: hole.x,
            y: hole.y
        }, hole.dest)
    );
    spaceShip = new SpaceShip(SPACESHIP_SIZE, SPACESHIP_POSITION);
}

function main() {
    ctx.font = "bolder 20px Courier New";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText(
        "Education Portal",
        Systems["main"].holes[0].x,
        Systems["main"].holes[0].y - 50
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "Technical Skills Portal",
        Systems["main"].holes[1].x,
        Systems["main"].holes[1].y - 50
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "Experience Portal",
        Systems["main"].holes[2].x,
        Systems["main"].holes[2].y - 50
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "Experience Portal",
        Systems["main"].holes[3].x,
        Systems["main"].holes[3].y - 50
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "Contact Me",
        Systems["main"].holes[4].x,
        Systems["main"].holes[4].y - 50
    );
}

function edu() {
    //College
    ctx.font = "italic 20px Courier New";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText(
        "Binghamton University, State University of New York, ",
        canvas.width / 2,
        150
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "Thomas J. Watson College of Engineering and Applied Science",
        canvas.width / 2,
        170
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "Bachelor of Science in Computer Science",
        canvas.width / 2,
        190
    );
    ctx.font = "20px Courier New";
    ctx.fillText("Overall GPA: 3.92", canvas.width / 2, 210);
    ctx.fillText("Major GPA: 4.0", canvas.width / 2, 230);
    ctx.fillText(
        "Relevant Coursework: Programming and Hardware Fundamentals,",
        canvas.width / 2,
        270
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "Professional Skills, Ethics, and CS Trends,",
        canvas.width / 2,
        290
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "Data Structures and Algorithms, Programming with Objects and Data Structures,",
        canvas.width / 2,
        310
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "Architecture from a Programmer Perspective (By Fall 2021)",
        canvas.width / 2,
        330
    );
    //High School
    ctx.font = "italic 20px Courier New";
    ctx.fillText("Islip High School", canvas.width / 2, 430);
    ctx.fillText(
        "STEM Academy Honors",
        canvas.width / 2,
        450
    );
    ctx.font = "20px Courier New";
    ctx.fillText(
        "Overall GPA: 100.77, Top 5% of class",
        canvas.width / 2,
        470
    );

    ctx.fillText(
        "Return",
        Systems["Education"].holes[0].x,
        Systems["Education"].holes[0].y - 50
    );
}

function techSkills() {
    ctx.font = "20px Courier New";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText(
        "Languages: Python, Java, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, C++",
        canvas.width / 2,
        150
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "Software and OS: VS Code, Eclipse, Sublime Text, Git, Logisim, Anaconda,",
        canvas.width / 2,
        190
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "Spyder, Microsoft Office, Linux, MacOS",
        canvas.width / 2,
        210
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "Additional: Familiar with MySQL, Arduino",
        canvas.width / 2,
        250
    );

    ctx.fillText("Return", canvas.width - 135, canvas.height - 155);
}

function exp1() {
    ctx.font = "20px Courier New";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText(
        "Binghamton University Rover Team, Software Engineer | Binghamton, NY",
        canvas.width / 2,
        150
    );
    ctx.fillText("October 2020 - Prestent", canvas.width / 2, 170);
    ctx.fillText(
        "-->Designed networks and code bases using C++ to maximize the efficiency",
        canvas.width / 2,
        190
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "   and performance of a model mars rover for The Mars Society University",
        canvas.width / 2,
        210
    );
    ctx.fillText("   Rover Challenge which takes place yearly", canvas.width / 2, 230);

    ctx.fillText(
        "-->Built a custom username/password page by interfacing Google Firebase",
        canvas.width / 2, 250
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "   with a HTML, CSS, and JavaScript page which allowed for user",
        canvas.width / 2,
        270
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "   authentication, permitting members of the team to view classified documents",
        canvas.width / 2,
        290
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "-->Prepared rover data by implementing Python script from scratch",
        canvas.width / 2,
        310
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "   using Matplotlib and NumPy which led to data visualization to be analyzed",
        canvas.width / 2,
        330
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "-->Constructed the GUI for the base station computer in C++ so",
        canvas.width / 2,
        350
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "   that all the components of the rover could be viewed in the most effective way",
        canvas.width / 2,
        370
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "JPMorgan Chase, Software Engineering Virtual Experience Program | Remote Role",
        canvas.width / 2,
        460
    );
    ctx.fillText("July 2020 - September 2020", canvas.width / 2, 480);
    ctx.fillText(
        "-->Modified an interface with a stock price data feed using Python 3 so that the system/data could be analyzed",
        canvas.width / 2,
        500
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "-->Implemented the perspective open-source code in preparation for data visualization",
        canvas.width / 2,
        520
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "-->Received certificate of completion by end of program",
        canvas.width / 2,
        540
    );
    ctx.fillText("Return", canvas.width - 135, canvas.height - 155);
}

function exp2() {
    ctx.font = "20px Courier New";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText(
        "Google CSSI, Coursera, Software Engineering Student | Remote Role",
        canvas.width / 2,
        150
    );
    ctx.fillText("June 2020 - August 2020", 50, 170);
    ctx.fillText(
        "-->Selected to take part in an invite-only Google Tech Student Development program",
        canvas.width / 2,
        190
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "-->Developed/designed personal web pages through CodePen using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript",
        canvas.width / 2,
        210
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "-->Reviewed, designed, and implemented a green screen algorithm in JavaScript",
        canvas.width / 2,
        230
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        " to transform images on our developed web pages",
        canvas.width / 2,
        250
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "-->Learned to hide data in images through the use of steganography",
        canvas.width / 2,
        270
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        "-->Received certificate of completion by end of program",
        canvas.width / 2,
        290
    );
    ctx.fillText("Return", canvas.width - 135, canvas.height - 155);
}

function draw() {
    // Clear screen
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 10, 60)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(150, 150, 150)";
    ctx.fillText(
        `--> You are in ${currentSystem}`,
        canvas.width / 2,
        canvas.height - canvas.height / 1.05
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        `--> Use the arrow keys to guide the rocket into different portals`,
        canvas.width - (canvas.width - 426),
        canvas.height - canvas.height / 1.08
    );
    ctx.fillText(
        `--> Refresh the page if you resize your window`,
        canvas.width - (canvas.width - 312),
        canvas.height - canvas.height / 1.11
    );

    //Adding section/system text information
    /*
      if(currentSystem=='main'){
          ctx.font ='bolder 20px Courier New'
          ctx.fillText('Education Portal', canvas.width/9, canvas.height/4);
          ctx.fillText('Technical Skills Portal', canvas.width/9.2, canvas.height/1.27);
          ctx.fillText('Experience Portal', canvas.width/2, canvas.height/4);
          ctx.fillText('Experience Portal', canvas.width/2, canvas.height/1.27);
          ctx.fillText('Contact Me', canvas.width/1.25, canvas.height/4);

      }
      */
  
   //Loading small stars
    ctx.shadowBlur = 1;
    for (
        var i = 1, j = 1; j < canvas.height; i += 100, i > canvas.width && ((i = 1), (j += 100)), circle(ctx, i, j, 1)
    );

    //loading medium stars
    ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
    for (
        var i = 1, j = 1; j < canvas.height; i += 150, i > canvas.width && ((i = 1), (j += 150)), circle(ctx, i, j, 2)
    );

    //loading larger stars
    ctx.shadowBlur = 3;
    for (
        var i = 1, j = 1; j < canvas.height; i += 225, i > canvas.width && ((i = 1), (j += 225)), circle(ctx, i, j, 3)
    );

    if (currentSystem == "main") {
        main();
    }
    if (currentSystem == "Education") {
        edu();
    }
    if (currentSystem == "Technical Skills") {
        techSkills();
    }
    if (currentSystem == "Experience1") {
        exp1();
    }
    if (currentSystem == "Experience2") {
        exp2();
    }

    if (currentSystem == "Contact Me") {
        ctx.fillText("Contact Me", 50, 450);
        ctx.fillText("Return", canvas.width - 135, canvas.height - 155);
    }

    // tick all objects
    spaceObjects.forEach((spaceObject) => spaceObject.tick());

    // Repeats
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

// Event Listeners
window.addEventListener("resize", (e) => {
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
});
document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyInput);
document.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyInput);
// Start the game
jump({
    dest: "main"
});
draw();
```